# What would be the scientific name of this worm

Tags: nomenclature

I saw this pic while crawling online and it was a bit different for me to predict which worm is this.

[image]

**Source:** http://www.seafishingtackle4u.com/softbaits/ragworms-latex-lures/

It appears somewhat different form other annelids as parapodia or setae are somewhat transparent and very attractive too.

What worm is this?

Comment: That worm is plastic.

Comment: So, in summary, it is Nereis effigiei

Comment: @J.Musser i too think the same as i cant see any correct parapodia on its body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Cornelius correctly pointed out, it's not a living worm :)

As to the question, what kind of worm they tried to imitate, I'd say, they had a [nereid](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&q=nereidae&tbm=isch) (errant, i.e. wandering) in mind and were likely inspired by the segmentation of *[Arenicola](https://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&q=arenicola&tbm=isch)* (sedentary), which together created this appearance, unrealistic for an errant polychaete: with the body segments outnumbering parapodia.

**EDIT:**

They also paid no attention to the head (a very important body part in polychaete systematics!), which seems to be absent. This feature could also be "inherited" from *Arenicola*, the head end of which is not prominent and bears no appendages.

Comment: what is the appandage like thing arising from mid part of its body

Comment: @agharehanabbas: hmm, you mean the hook?

Comment: yes can i get any details about its morphology anatomy and role in daily physiology?, i think it is special character of polycheate nerieds

Comment: [The hook is actually part of the lure.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fishing_lure)

Answer (score 2):

If you would have read the text from the source of that image (which by the way you didn't mention, I did a Google Image search and edited your question to include it), you would have known that what is seen in the picture is not a living thing, it is a latex [fishing lure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fishing_lure):

> Product Description: Sandworm/Ragworm 8″ size, sure fire fish catching lures. Costing less than live worms, but lasting much longer, never be without worms again.

Source: http://www.seafishingtackle4u.com/softbaits/ragworms-latex-lures/

Comment: Rotf lol Awesome answer